# List to String to List Python 3

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, exec

I need to convert a list into a string and then do the reverse process. Note that one script will convert List->String and another script will convert String->List, so store the list in a variable is not a solution. Use split(', ') or similar is not a solution either in all cases. So, as a challange I invite you to do the conversion in the following example:

```
l = ['ab,.cd\'ac"', b'\x80', '\r\nHi, !', b'\x01']
str_l = str(l)
```

I have tried one thing that worked: using exec() built-in function but people says is not a good practice, so I invite you to give me another alternative. Also I am having problems using exec() inside a function but that's another question that you can check -> [Using exec() inside a function Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078114/using-exec-inside-a-function-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
str_l = ("|").join(l)
```

Which gives you your first string. Then do:

```
l_2 = str_l.split("|")
```

Which gives you your second list.

[image]

Comment: It fails for two reasons, first:

    str_l = ("|").join(l)

Raises TypeError:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in
> <module>
>     str_l = ("|").join(l) TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, bytes found

And the second one is that my lists contains all kind of symbols so you just can't use "|" in the real example. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Worked for me. Added a picture in my solution.

Comment: I'm using python 3.4 and I get TypeError in line 2. Also, your final list if different to initial list (bytes were replaced by strings) and as I said above, you just can't use | because the real example contains all kind of symbols. 
Thanks again!