# Using exec() inside a function Python 3

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, exec

I know, I know.. I shouldn't use exec() built-in function, it's not a good practice. However, I need to use it for a good reason (you can find the reason here: [List to String to List Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073975/list-to-string-to-list-python-3). And you can suggest a better idea there). So, the problem is the following:

```
def function():
    exec("l = [1, 2, 3]")
    for i in l:
        print(i)

function()
```

Raise:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       function()   File "", line 3, in function
>       for i in l: NameError: name 'l' is not defined

Note that this is a simplified version, in this example the use of exec() seems unnecessary but in the real case it's not. Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT**

The answer can be found and very well discussed in [Behavior of exec function in Python 2 and Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086040/behaviour-of-exec-function-in-python-2-and-python-3)

A working code for the problem is the following:

```
def function():
    d = locals()
    exec("l = [1, 2, 3]", globals(), d)
    for i in d['l']:
        print(i)

function()
```

Thanks to  @Martijn Pieters

Comment: What you excatly want to do?

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't test correctly, indeed it works in the global, but not in the local scope.